# Need light formula to get some counts in large data sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an employee data base that contains names and 8 movement types (Ex. Recruitment, Resignation....etc). Also I have starting head counts.
What I need to do is calculating movement counts and head counts based on the month for 12 months. Currently i am using `SUMIF` formula to calculate all these and the thing is excel will be very slow with all formulas. Appreciate if anyone can help me on this. See the image below for sample of the formula and I need to insert this formula in more than 600 lines.

[image]

Comment: Try changing your calculation settings to manual if it isn't already. You can then manually update the sheet when you need to which might be the answer to your problem.

Comment: How about using a pivot table? Categorizing and counting data from tables is what they do, much faster than a bunch of formulas. If that's not possible, if part of your formula is repeated for multiple cells in a row, then consider moving that part to its own helper column. On another note, please just pasted your formula into your question.

Comment: If not using a pivot table (which is my favorite here) then VBA will be the best answer... this way you only need to run all the data once and then output the whole 2d-array. This way it also will not recalculate every time you do a change (only if you want it to, if using a sub instead of a UDF)

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table would be a good way to go, but by the look of your criteria you'll need to create 'helper columns' to ensure your data is ready for aggregation in a Pivot table.

For instance in your master data tab, add a new column called 'MatchesCriteria' or words to that effect, and build a formula in that column that checks for all of the criteria that you want to have the report based on, and returns a 1 or a 0, e.g.

```
=IF( (IF(C2="Recruitment",1,0)+IF(D2="Secondment In",1,0)) > 0 , 1 , 0)
```

Then run a pivot table including the 'Plant' column in your Rows, the month column in your columns and the 'MatchesCriteria' in your data values, and switch the calculation type to 'SUM' rather than 'COUNT'.

This will do the trick and will refresh in a flash compared to evaluating all of those countif statements.

Comment: better `=OR(C2="Recruitment",D2="Secondment In")*1` or just `(C2<>"Recruitment")*(D2<>"Secondment In")` and go for 0's

Comment: Excellent addition Dirk (to think I even started with nested IFs!)

Comment: Hi Chris & Dirk I can't understand this formula since I have to get data from 4 columns which include few choices. I need to get correct month from 12months in A:A, need to get movment from 8types in B:B, employee type from 3types C:C, SBU from 21 entries in D:D. Then I need each and every category counts seperately. Hope you could understand what I'm saying.

Comment: So in Column F:F for example you could make a formula that checks your other columns to see if they should be included in your overall analysis and return a 1 or a 0. Does that make it any clearer?